# man who is the doctor..or man who the doctor is

Tags: clauses

What is the grammatically correct clause mentioned below ?

1.(a) Isobel,whose brother john was,(had heard the joke before.) or
(b)Isobel,whose brother was john,(had heard the joke before.)

2.(a)John,who Isobel's brother was... or
(b)John,who was Isobel's brother.......

Comment: It is (b) in both cases. I kindly suggest you have a look at our sister-site, [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) that is more suited to these kind of  questions.

Comment: 1) b. 2) b. :-)

Comment: I am waiting for the joke's punchline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, in both cases, b) is normal and a) is not.

1a) is grammatical, but unusual. By moving *John* before the verb, it makes *John* the subject of the relative clause: it would only be used if we expected the hearer to know John and so we were identifying Isobel with reference to him. Even then it is awkward, and we'd be much more likely to say *Isobel, [who was] John's sister*.

2a) is not grammatical, because again *Isobel's brother* is the subject of the relative clause; but *was* must take a complement, unless there is one implied from a previous clause (eg *I don't know if anybody else was hungry, but Isobel's brother was*, where a repeated "hungry" has been elided). There is no such previous complement to be assumed here.